# Is there a CLR that runs on the CLR?

Tags: .net, clr, cil

**I was wondering if there was a .NET-compatible CLR that was implemented using the CLI** (common language infrastructure), e.g., using .NET itself, or at least if there were any resources that would help with building one.

Basically, something like a .NET program that loads assemblies as MemoryStreams, parses the bytecode, constructs the types, and executes the instructions. Optionally, it can JIT-compile to standard IL using Reflection.Emit or however.

**I don't want to *compile* a .NET language to be run by the original CLR. I want a CLR that's *written* in a .NET language** (not unmanaged C++ or C as it usually is) **and *runs* CIL.** If done right, it should be able to run itself.

Any thoughts on using Mono.Cecil for this kind of thing?

Comment: But...why? It seems a very odd thing to do, and I can't come up with any possible use-cases.

Comment: @Davr: Because then you could run a CLR in the CLR in the CLR!

Comment: @Davr a lot of comes to the same arguments as AOP but a CLR-based CLR can also be even more "managed" than a normal CLR since it can reflect over itself and do modifications, including optimization, not possible with a plain old CLR. Plus, it's just cool.

Comment: I actually do have a use-case: subsetting or redirecting bindings to platform libraries such as mscorlib.  For example, exposing DateTime.Now to untrusted code is a bad thing...

Comment: A CLR on the CRL on the CLR...I think I just had a Stack Overflow

Comment: Maybe partially by compiling coreclr as C++/CLI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there are currently any standalone .net VMs that are self hosting but both [Cosmos](http://www.gocosmos.org) and [SharpOS](http://sharpos.org) are .net runtimes written in C#.

It may be possible to reuse some of their runtime code to extra a standalone runtime. Cosmos can be used to host a custom application on boot: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/CosmosIntro.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You should check out the [IKVM.NET Project](http://www.ikvm.net/). It includes a Java Virtual Machine written in .NET.

http://www.ikvm.net/

I know it's not an actual CLR that runs on top of the CLR, but it's the closest thing I know of that does what you want.

Comment: I'm aware of IKVM but yes it may be helpful to have a look at.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of one, but ideas frm JVM running on JVM should be helpful.

- [Jikes RVM](http://jikesrvm.org/)
- [Maxine VM](http://maxine.dev.java.net/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to expand your definition of "runs CIL" to "JIT-Compiles CIL to Native Code," then you should look at the [Managed Operating System Alliance](http://www.mosa-project.org/) -- a group of people (myself included) working toward creating the runtime pieces necessary to write a managed operating system kernel.

Currently, there is quite a bit left to do, but it is possible to JIT-compile and run simple methods (Win32 only -- we currently use P/Invoke to create the native code buffers)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in principle by combining technologies:

- [Jikes RVM](http://jikesrvm.org/) is a Java Virtual Machine implementation written in Java.
- [IKVM.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IKVM.NET), an implementation of the Java platform on .NET.

It might also be possible to take [Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29), compile to LLVM bytecode, compile the bytecode to Javascript using [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten), and run the Javascript on .NET using any of various interpreters.

Answer (score -2):

Look at the System.Reflection.Emit namespace, specifically the ILGenerator class.

You can emit IL on the fly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator_members.aspx

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. I want to execute IL, not compile C#.

Comment: Perhaps do a little research before downmodding me.

Comment: I didn't downmod you and even then you had a different answer (i.e., CodeDom)